# Arrays output not giving proper result in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, data-structures, logic

Here, I have created an array that will print the output, but the second output did not give a valid result, like `I work as a Web Dev in Ind.` I want, but it prints `I work as a Sam in 27.` So, what do I need to change about this program?

```js
const arr = [
  (name, age) => {
    console.log(`My name is ${name} and I am ${age} years old.`);
  },
  (job, city) => {
    console.log(`I work as a ${job} in ${city}.`);
  }
];

for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  arr[i]("Sam", 27, "Web Dev", "Ind");
}
```

Comment: 2 seperate function u need pass parameters separately

Comment: Your code always passes four parameters to the functions, but each of them is only declared with *two* parameters. The functions can't tell which parameters are which values.

Comment: Parameters are positional. The first and second arguments are `"Sam"` and `27` regardless of how you name them. JS doesn't magically know that the name `job` should somehow match the third argument, rather than the first when you've defined it first.

Comment: keep a params array `const params = [["Sam", 27],["Web Dev", "Ind"]]` then pass like `arr[i](...params[i])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get something like the effect you want, you can use destructuring:

```js
const arr = [
  ({name, age}) => {
    console.log(`My name is ${name} and I am ${age} years old.`);
  },
  ({job, city}) => {
    console.log(`I work as a ${job} in ${city}.`);
  }
];

for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  arr[i]({ name: "Sam", age: 27, job: "Web Dev", city: "Ind"});
}
```

Destructuring allows each function to decide which properties to pluck out of the passed object. You could add another function:

```js
const arr = [
  ({name, age}) => {
    console.log(`My name is ${name} and I am ${age} years old.`);
  },
  ({job, city}) => {
    console.log(`I work as a ${job} in ${city}.`);
  },
  ({city, age}) => {
    console.log(`At ${age} years old, I find ${city} to be a lot of fun.`);
  }
];

for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  arr[i]({ name: "Sam", age: 27, job: "Web Dev", city: "Ind"});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing all 4 parameters into each function, which only takes 2 parameters.

In your code:

```
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  arr[i]("Sam", 27, "Web Dev", "Ind");
}
```

Basically what is being run are these two function calls:

```
arr[0]("Sam", 27, "Web Dev", "Ind")
arr[1]("Sam", 27, "Web Dev", "Ind")
```

Where what you want to run is this:

```
arr[0]("Sam", 27)
arr[1]("Web Dev", "Ind")
```

So you will have to go about passing your parameters, or executing your functions in a different way.